# Laravel selectRaw with joined table data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the following to sum a total column:

```
$hive_count = Hive::where('active','true')
                      ->groupBy('hive_type_id')
                      ->selectRaw('sum(total) as sum, hive_type_id')
                      ->pluck('sum','hive_type_id');
```

But rather than using the hive_type_id for the array key, I would like to access the hive_type name from the hive_types table (column 'name'). I have tried hive_type_id.name but this did not work.

Models: Hive & HiveType

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add your models to the OP.

Comment: Have added, Hive and HiveType

Comment: You've to add the columns of every one and the type of relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to access the hive_type name from the hive_types table (column 'name').

You've to join the table `hive_types` in your query so you can access the `name` :

```
$hive_count = DB::table('hives')
                  ->where('active','true')
                  ->join('hive_types', 'hives.hive_type_id', '=', 'hive_types.id')
                  ->groupBy('hive_type_id','hive_types.name')
                  ->selectRaw('sum(total) as sum, hive_types.name as name')
                  ->pluck('sum','name');
```

Comment: I need the hive_type name within the original query so I can use it as the array key. I don't see how your answer achieves that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got the following error:
`Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "hive_types.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`